# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' (Problem with Python3.9)

Tags: pandas, python-3.9

Initially, I ran experiments on python3, which supports Pandas perfectly. Since our lab recently upgraded the server to an **RTX 3000 series GPU**, **it supports Python 3.9**, not previous versions. For that, when I ran the tests in python3.9 (python3.9 code file.py), the following error occurred:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

Then I ran 'pip install pandas' and found that the requirements had already been met; here's further information:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.1.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2021.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.4 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)
```

But when I ran the file again, I received the same issue: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

How can we install solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, our lab server supports various Python versions, and I was executing my code files from a directory with a Python version of 3.6, which caused the issue. Therefore, we must either change our project directory to Python 3.9 and install Pandas there or use the following command as instructed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/45833).

```
python3.9 -m pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are running pip with the correct python version. `./.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages` in your error indicates that you are still using python3.6.
If you are using IPython, you can type `pip install pandas` directly in the interactive mode (not in the terminal), which uses the proper Python version then.
In general, I would create a virtual environment using `/path/to/python39 -m venv ~/myvenv`, then active it using `source ~/myvenv/bin/activate` and install packages then - especially if using a graphics card you may need different package versions for different projects.

Comment: @DeeepKling, thanks alot man. Somehow it help but I am not using Ipython. I solved it via entering the command `python3.9 -m pip install pandas` on the terminal. Please mark my answer and question up. Thanks.